# Obtaining relevant fields from Watson Discovery search results as Watson assistant response

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant, watson-discovery

I am using watson assistant webhooks to call a watson discovery query action. Using `$webhook_result_1.passages`, I'm getting all the passage fields. I want the assistant response as the `passage_text` field only.
I have tried everything like `$webhook_result_1.passages.passage_text`, `$webhook_result_1.passages[0].passage_text` but nothing seems to work.

```
{
"matching_results": 14,
"session_token": "1_xvrscQ9w1x7chIp2_HWOk4wS8K",
"passages": [
    {
        "document_id": "3a5efee70d8cc9d70e2b94d22c15e2d1_8",
        "passage_score": 8.335406752877208,
        "passage_text": "If you have a furnace or boiler installed: 1. Select the heating menu. 2. Configure the heater type:  Furnace: Optimizes ecobee3 for systems using forced air  Boiler: Optimizes your ecobee3 for systems using radiators or in-floor heat. 3.",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 240,
        "field": "text"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Expression language methods](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-arrays)

For a context variable named `testarray` with value `[{"text":"value"},{"text":"2"}]` in the dialog response text I can use this to output the 'text' property from the first object:

```
 <? context.testarray.get(0).get("text").getAsString() ?>
```

You may therefore need:

```
Passage is : <?context.webhook_result_1.passages.get(0).get("passage_text").getAsString() ?>
```

Comment: It worked. Also, can I use Watson Discovery to read a restaurant menu? Line by line not in a paragraph.